# Impulse on different screen sizes Spritekit Xcode

Tags: ios, screen, sprite-kit, physics, skphysicsbody

Hi I'm making a game where you tap to give an upward impulse to the ball of lets for example say a cgvector (4,0).

This if for both 4inch and 3.5 inch retina displays.

Will the impulse move the ball the same amount in pixels or same amount relative to the screen size different. I need the ball to move the same amount relative to the size or else the game will become easier on i5's . I have an idea of how to achieve it.

Could someone with knowledge of how impulse works clear this up?

Only asking because i recently played it on a i5 and got higher scores than usually on the i4

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

physics simulation does not depend on screen size, however the scene may be scaled (see scaleMode) which can affect how much of the scene you can see on each device.

Comment: i.e. it will move the same pixels?

Comment: and it WAS actually easier?

Comment: a body with a given velocity will move at the same speed (in points, not pixels) regardless of screen size